# Very slow Wi-Fi (normal on cable)

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, wireless-access-point

I have a 120mbps link and it works perfectly on cable connection, but when I switch to Wi-Fi I can hardly reach 5mbps. I've tried several solutions presented on several forums, but nothing helped. Here goes some information:

**Setup:** My router is configured as an access point for the internet provided router (DHCP disabled, cable connected to lan port).

**AP Router:** Tp-Link TL-WR940N, V3 (firmware up to date, maximum speed is 450mbps)

**Mode:** 11bgn Mixed (other available options: 11bg Mixed)

**Channel:** Automatic (currently channel 3, only one other network using it)

**Channel width:** Automatic (currently 40MHz)

**Obstacles and distance:** Currently about 3 meters away with a single door between device and router, but it was also tested with varying distances and no obstacles without improvement)

**Main laptop wireless card:** Intel® Dual Band Wireless-AC 3165 (Drivers up to date)

Cabled connection is stable when connected to either routers.

Wi-Fi problem is consistent across all connected devices. Any ideas?

**Edit:** I've set the channel to 11 (only 1 other network using it) and disabled bluetooth from the main laptop and cellphone (connected to the same network, always close to the main laptop). While it did show some minor improvement, I still can't get past 9mbps on the wi-fi. ISP-provided router wi-fi is currently disabled and all cabled tests on ISP and AP router are withing acceptable bounds (100mbps or more).

Comment: Its possible that there is interference from another (non WIFI) device which is eating spectrum and causing issues.  Not sure how you would find and fix that without professional equipment though - as it won't show up on WIFI analyser software.   I guess you could try getting hints based on signal to noise ratio.  [ baby monitors and old cordless phones (dect 2.4 ghz ones ?, cheap IOT devices with non-WIFI 2.4 gig)  are often causes, but are not the only possibilities ]

Comment: @davidgo I've disabled wi-fi and bluetooth from all electronic devices (laptops, smartphones, Tvs) without any improvement. There are no other  wireless devices in the house either.

Comment: Yes, I can see you are doing all you can - but I never said the devices needed to be devices in your control.  Unfortunately WIFI can be unreliable due to the entirely legal action of others.  How far are your neighbours, and are you able to borrow a WIFI router from a friend and see if it performs any better?   It would be unusual that you would not get better performance as you get closer to the router [ because you increase the Signal to Noise ratio ]

Answer (score 1):

Your AP is a 3x3 N and your main laptop wireless card is a 1x1 AC, so the subset they both support is 1x1 N, which is only 150 Mbps with 40MHz-wide channels. If you're using Bluetooth on your laptop, or if both channels 3 and 7 are not nice and clean, your devices might be forced to use 20MHz mode most of the time, which knocks you down to 72.2 Mbps. Wi-Fi is half-duplex, and even with 802.11n's packet aggregation you can only expect TCP/IP throughput of about 60% of the PHY rate. At 3 meters though a door you might not be maintaining the top PHY rate.

All that said, It'd still expect you to get better than 20Mbps in the scenario as you've described it so far.

Put your AP on channel 1 or 11. Also, what's the story with the ISP-provided router? Does it do Wi-Fi as well? If so, did disable that, or put it on a non-overlapping channel with a different SSID so you know it's not getting in the way of your test? Wait, you basically can't. By using channel 3 in 40MHz mode, you're basically using channels 3 and 7 together, which means you've basically set yourself up so that anything anywhere in the band will interfere with you. Again, put your AP on channel 1 or 11 so that it leaves the other end of the band free for other uses.

I'd also do a performance test plugged into another LAN port of the TP-Link, so you can see if the TP-Link itself or the Ethernet between the two routers has problems.

Comment: Hello @Spiff, thanks for your help! I've set the channel to 11 (only 1 other network using it) and disabled bluetooth from the main laptop and cellphone (connected to the same network, always close to the main laptop). While it did show some minor improvement, I still can't get past 9mbps on the wi-fi. ISP-provided router wi-fi is currently disabled and all cabled tests on ISP and AP router are withing acceptable bounds (100mbps or more)